# Creating an isochrone from GTFS data

Tags: isochrone, general-transit-feed-specification

I want to create an isochrone map, with a single stating point at first, from standard GTFS data.
I've started by filtering only the relevant areas both in Stops and Shapes files, but now I'm not sure how should I proceed next.

Also, is there some recommended tools for it? I feel like it should be a rather common task

Edit: OpenTripPlanner (1.5) has this feature and so has the latest version (2.3) in which it still development

Comment: The old version of OpenTripPlanner (1.5) can, for example, do it.

Comment: @MrXsquared Just found it too, thanks!